# Django - Display Jsonresponse after Fetch POST

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am currently posting audio through javascript fetch to a Django server, post-processing it and returning a JsonResponse.

I now would like to display the JsonResponse on my website as they come in.

I understand I need some type of listener in my JS that gets triggered with every POST request that is being made, probably after my fetch function or maybe a separate function?

My Js

```
function makeLink(){
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
  let fd = new FormData;
  fd.append("audioRecording", blob);
  fetch("https://localhost/news/audio/", {method:"POST", body:fd})
  .then(response => response.ok)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

This POSTS the audio and triggers the following views.py:

```
def audio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Store audio
        #Make some API calls
        return JsonResponse({"abc":123})
```

Now let's suppose I have a TextField in plain html and I would like the JsonResponse to be displayed in the TextField without the need of reloading the website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="text">
Response should be here
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Then you need to do this in your javascript part. Now you only print your response into the console (console.log(res)). Here you can add your response to your textarea with jquery or javascript. Try: $('#text').append(res);

Comment: Also I would recommend you to work with the django-restframework. I also work with this framework. Try a look -> http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Hi, that res is not the same response I want to append. @Patrick85

Comment: What response do You want to append? Your question was how to append a response to your textfield. With jquery it is possible how i wrote You before. Append your response to the textfield.

Comment: @Patrick85 You are right, nevermind. I had to change response.ok with response.json()

Comment: If my answer works for you then please vote my answer ;) Thanks

Comment: @Patrick85 Shouldn't you post an answer and not a comment ? I'll be glad to select it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my post, which i also commented to your question:

If you want to add your response to your custom textbox, you need to do this with javascript.
Actualy you only print your response into the web-console:

```
console.log(res)
```

This part could you change to add your response to your textbox. 
With jquery it could look so:

```
$('#text').append(res);   // If 'res' is your response you want to add
```

If you want to add something other then only replace 'res'.

Also I would recommend you to work with the django-restframework. I also work with this framework. Try a look -> [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)